# Encryption pass phrase limited length

Tags: encryption, passphrase

I installed ubuntu 15.x using the encryption option in the installation menu.  When it requested a pass phrase, I found it would only accept 15 characters.  I've used encryption before and have used 4K files for a passphrase.  Is this a known bug or limited to 15 characters?  It appears when you enter 15 characters into the passphrase GUI, both entry and verification.  If you add one more character the GUI claims the passphrase doesn't match.